# GROUP BY not working when applying case in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

My aim here is to get the `repairNo` if the count value is equals to 1 else returns a default value as null or something. Here before applying the case statement works fine but after using case, not returns as expected. Returns each item as a single row. No group by applied. How to solve this. Any suggestions welcome.

```
SELECT kunden.kundennr, 
       kunden.firma, 
       kunden.vorname, 
       kunden.nachname, 
       kunden.mobil, 
       kunden.email, 
       kunden.geburtsdatum, 
       kunden.isdatenschutzerklaerung, 
       Count(reparaturen.reparaturnr) AS Counts, 
       CASE 
         WHEN Count(reparaturen.reparaturnr) = 1 THEN Cast( 
         reparaturen.reparaturnr AS NVARCHAR(20)) 
         ELSE 0 
       END                            AS RepairNo 
FROM   kunden 
       LEFT JOIN reparaturen 
              ON reparaturen.kundennr = kunden.kundennr 
       LEFT JOIN personal AS PersonalAngenommen 
              ON reparaturen.personalnr = PersonalAngenommen.personalnr 
       LEFT JOIN lieferanten 
              ON reparaturen.kennnr = lieferanten.lieferantennr 
                 AND reparaturen.kenntyp = 2 
       LEFT JOIN personal 
              ON reparaturen.kennnr = personal.personalnr 
                 AND reparaturen.kenntyp = 1 
WHERE  kunden.geloescht = 0 
       AND ( kunden.firma LIKE '%G%' ) 
GROUP  BY kunden.kundennr, 
          kunden.firma, 
          kunden.vorname, 
          kunden.nachname, 
          kunden.mobil, 
          kunden.email, 
          kunden.geburtsdatum, 
          kunden.isdatenschutzerklaerung, 
          reparaturen.reparaturnr 
ORDER  BY kunden.nachname, 
          kunden.vorname
```

Comment: What is the error message, if any, or can you show us some sample data which explains your problem?

Comment: The group-by is not working bro.The rows are not grouped if 10 rows means those all are displayed in a separate row. But I need the Total count as 10, and if it's one means it's corresponding RepairNo.

Comment: The value for one column is always different, like ID type. Omit this column from your select and groupby statements, u will be fine.

Comment: Remove Reparaturen.ReparaturNr from the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: After I remove got error 'Column 'Reparaturen.ReparaturNr' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.'

Comment: Perhaps consider doing what the error message tells you to do?  Either put that column in the `GROUP BY` or put it in an aggregate?  I recommend `MAX(Reparaturen.ReparaturNr)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have `Reparaturen.ReparaturNr` in the `CASE` because you don't `GROUP BY` it.

*(Follows on from the comment that **correctly** tells you to remove it from the `GROUP BY`.)*

After removing it from the `GROUP BY`, then try...

```
   CASE 
     WHEN Count(reparaturen.reparaturnr) = 1 THEN Cast( 
     MAX(reparaturen.reparaturnr) AS NVARCHAR(20)) 
     ELSE 0 
   END                            AS RepairNo
```

Then you're using an aggregate function, like the error message tells you to.

```
SELECT kunden.kundennr, 
       kunden.firma, 
       kunden.vorname, 
       kunden.nachname, 
       kunden.mobil, 
       kunden.email, 
       kunden.geburtsdatum, 
       kunden.isdatenschutzerklaerung, 
       Count(reparaturen.reparaturnr) AS Counts, 
       CASE 
         WHEN Count(reparaturen.reparaturnr) = 1 THEN Cast( 
         MAX(reparaturen.reparaturnr) AS NVARCHAR(20)) 
         ELSE 0 
       END                            AS RepairNo 
FROM   kunden 
       LEFT JOIN reparaturen 
              ON reparaturen.kundennr = kunden.kundennr 
       LEFT JOIN personal AS PersonalAngenommen 
              ON reparaturen.personalnr = PersonalAngenommen.personalnr 
       LEFT JOIN lieferanten 
              ON reparaturen.kennnr = lieferanten.lieferantennr 
                 AND reparaturen.kenntyp = 2 
       LEFT JOIN personal 
              ON reparaturen.kennnr = personal.personalnr 
                 AND reparaturen.kenntyp = 1 
WHERE  kunden.geloescht = 0 
       AND ( kunden.firma LIKE '%G%' ) 
GROUP  BY kunden.kundennr, 
          kunden.firma, 
          kunden.vorname, 
          kunden.nachname, 
          kunden.mobil, 
          kunden.email, 
          kunden.geburtsdatum, 
          kunden.isdatenschutzerklaerung
ORDER  BY kunden.nachname, 
          kunden.vorname
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to calculate repairno in a different query. Please try:

```
;with cte as (

SELECT
Kunden.KundenNr
, Kunden.Firma
, Kunden.Vorname
, Kunden.Nachname
, Kunden.Mobil
, Kunden.EMail
, Kunden.Geburtsdatum
, Kunden.IsDatenschutzerklaerung
,COUNT(Reparaturen.ReparaturNr) as Counts
FROM Kunden
 LEFT JOIN Reparaturen on Reparaturen.KundenNr = Kunden.KundenNr 
 LEFT JOIN Personal AS PersonalAngenommen ON Reparaturen.PersonalNr = PersonalAngenommen.PersonalNr 
 LEFT JOIN Lieferanten ON Reparaturen.KennNr = Lieferanten.LieferantenNr AND Reparaturen.KennTyp = 2
 LEFT JOIN Personal ON Reparaturen.KennNr = Personal.PersonalNr AND Reparaturen.KennTyp = 1
WHERE Kunden.Geloescht = 0
AND (
Kunden.Firma Like '%G%'
)GROUP BY Kunden.KundenNr,Kunden.Firma, Kunden.Vorname
 , Kunden.Nachname 
 , Kunden.Mobil 
 , Kunden.EMail 
 , Kunden.Geburtsdatum 
 , Kunden.IsDatenschutzerklaerung


)
select *, 
       case when Counts = 1 Then cast(r.reparaturnr as nvarchar(20)) else 0 end as RepairNo
from cte
LEFT JOIN reparaturen r
ON r.kundenNr = cte.kundenNr
```

Comment: Here I'm getting the count again from Cte result but I need it's corrosponding ReparaturNr. How do I get this?

Comment: The op is casting a column to a varchar, you're casting the count of that column to a varchar.  That's not remotely the same.

Comment: @MatBailie which column the OP converts into varchar, I can't see it. I only see nvarchar.

Comment: @SPYder the result u get from cte is the corrosponding reparaturNr. Count is calculated based on reparaturNr

Comment: Don't be pedantic.  `NVARCHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `NVARCHAR(20)`, ***whatever***.  The OP has `CAST(Reparaturen.ReparaturNr AS NVARCHAR(20))`, but you have `CAST(COUNT(Reparaturen.ReparaturNr) AS NVARCHAR(20))`

Comment: I dont need count value from cte. I need that reparaturNr corresponding count value = 1. How to achieve this?

Comment: @MatBailie Sorry, I got u wrong at the first step, wasn't trying to be pedantic. thanks for the warning, updated my answer.

Comment: @SPYder Please try now.

Comment: If there are multiple rows in `Reparaturen`, you just undid the `GROUP BY` by joining on it a second time.

Comment: Great @ErayBalkanli Finally You save my Day ! Thanks alot Working as I expected!

Comment: Umm, that's a LOT of effort to just avoid putting `MAX()` around the problem column as per my answer.

Comment: Glad to help @SPYder , i'd appreciate if u select the answer as the correct one by clicking the tick on the left. Have a good day.

Comment: Again a problem occurs @ErayBalkanli. If it's more than one item returns with same id means then returns with separate rows as i said earlier bro..How to fix this?

Comment: @SPYder are the values for any of those fields unique: Kunden.Geburtsdatum
,and Kunden.IsDatenschutzerklaerung ?

Comment: Thanks For the contribution. I found @MatBailie solution works without using cte even If more than one row returns.

Comment: all are same bro But the count value getting only differs and I'm getting the right answer as stated below one.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to watch out when using GROUP BY and a filter like where. When you are using the GROUP BY you should use the HAVING clause. Using the where can cause unwanted anomalies.

Comment: This is untrue. There is nothing stopping you using `WHERE x=1 GROUP BY y HAVING MAX(Y) = 2`.  I use WHERE with GROUP BY a lot more often than I use HAVING.

Answer (score -1):

a blind guess would be that you would need to have the 0 as a text by using single quotes

```
case when COUNT(Reparaturen.ReparaturNr) = 1 Then cast(Reparaturen.ReparaturNr as nvarchar(20)) else '0' end as RepairNo
```

Comment: It's also not working bro..Any other solutions to fix this?